# How to do a point in polygon query efficiently using geopandas?

Tags: python, geopandas

I have a shapefile that has all the counties for the US, and I am doing a bunch of queries at a lat/lon point and then finding what county the point lies in. Right now I am just looping through all the counties and doing pnt.within(county). This isn't very efficient. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Check the spatial join: https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mergingdata.html#spatial-joins

Comment: Your question would be more suited for gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your situation looks like a typical case where `spatial joins` are useful. The idea of spatial joins is to merge data using geographic coordinates instead of using attributes.

Three possibilities in `geopandas`:

- `intersects`
- `within`
- `contains`

It seems like you want `within`, which is possible using the following syntax:

```py
geopandas.sjoin(points, polygons, how="inner", op='within')
```

**Note: You need to have installed `rtree` to be able to perform such operations. If you need to install this dependency, use `pip` or `conda` to install it**

## Example

As an example, let's plot European cities. The two example datasets are

```py
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
cities = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
countries = world[world['continent'] == "Europe"].rename(columns={'name':'country'})

countries.head(2)
    pop_est     continent   country     iso_a3  gdp_md_est  geometry
18  142257519   Europe  Russia  RUS     3745000.0   MULTIPOLYGON (((178.725 71.099, 180.000 71.516...
21  5320045     Europe  Norway  -99     364700.0    MULTIPOLYGON (((15.143 79.674, 15.523 80.016, ...

cities.head(2)
    name    geometry
0   Vatican City    POINT (12.45339 41.90328)
1   San Marino  POINT (12.44177 43.93610)
```

`cities` is a worldwide dataset and `countries` is an European wide dataset.

Both dataset need to be in the same projection system. If not, use `.to_crs` before merging.

```py
data_merged = geopandas.sjoin(cities, countries, how="inner", op='within')
```

Finally, to see the result let's do a map

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20,10))
data_merged.plot(axes=ax)
countries.plot(axes=ax, alpha=0.25, linewidth=0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

and the underlying dataset merges together the information we need

```py
data_merged.head(5)

    name    geometry    index_right     pop_est     continent   country     iso_a3  gdp_md_est
0   Vatican City    POINT (12.45339 41.90328)   141     62137802    Europe  Italy   ITA     2221000.0
1   San Marino  POINT (12.44177 43.93610)   141     62137802    Europe  Italy   ITA     2221000.0
192     Rome    POINT (12.48131 41.89790)   141     62137802    Europe  Italy   ITA     2221000.0
2   Vaduz   POINT (9.51667 47.13372)    114     8754413     Europe  Austria     AUT     416600.0
184     Vienna  POINT (16.36469 48.20196)   114     8754413     Europe  Austria     AUT     416600.0
```

Here, I used `inner` join method but that's a parameter you can change if, for instance, you want to keep all points, including those not within a polygon.