# PANDAS-GEOPANDAS: Localization of points in a shapefile

Tags: python, pandas, geolocation, shapefile, geopandas

Using pandas and geopandas, I would like to define a function to be applied to each row of a dataframe which operates as follows:
INPUT: column with coordinates
OUTPUT: zone in which the point falls.

I tried with this, but it takes very long.

```
def zone_assign(point,zones,codes):
    try:
        zone_label=zones[zones['geometry'].contains(point)][codes].values[0]
    except:
        zone_label=np.NaN
    return(zone_label)
```

where:
point is the cell of the row which contains geographical coordinates;
zones is the shapefile imported with geopandas;
codes is the column of the shapefile which contains label to be assigned to the point.

Comment: You are looking for `geopandas.sjoin`.(https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/mergingdata.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of the answer, is taken from another answer I made earlier [that needed within rather than contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61124544/how-to-do-a-point-in-polygon-query-efficiently-using-geopandas/61245467#61245467)

Your situation looks like a typical case where `spatial joins` are useful. The idea of spatial joins is to merge data using geographic coordinates instead of using attributes.

Three possibilities in `geopandas`:

- `intersects`
- `within`
- `contains`

It seems like you want `contains`, which is possible using the following syntax:

```py
geopandas.sjoin(polygons, points, how="inner", op='contains')
```

**Note: You need to have installed `rtree` to be able to perform such operations. If you need to install this dependency, use `pip` or `conda` to install it**

## Example

As an example, let's take a random sample of cities and plot countries associated. The two example datasets are

```py
import geopandas
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
cities = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_cities'))
cities = cities.sample(n=50, random_state=1)

world.head(2)

    pop_est     continent   name    iso_a3  gdp_md_est  geometry
0   920938  Oceania     Fiji    FJI     8374.0  MULTIPOLYGON (((180.00000 -16.06713, 180.00000...
1   53950935    Africa  Tanzania    TZA     150600.0    POLYGON ((33.90371 -0.95000, 34.07262 -1.05982...


cities.head(3)
    name    geometry
196     Bogota  POINT (-74.08529 4.59837)
95  Tbilisi     POINT (44.78885 41.72696)
173     Seoul   POINT (126.99779 37.56829)
```

`world` is a worldwide dataset and `cities` is a subset.

Both dataset need to be in the same projection system. If not, use `.to_crs` before merging.

```py
data_merged = geopandas.sjoin(countries, cities, how="inner", op='contains')
```

Finally, to see the result let's do a map

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(20,10))
data_merged.plot(axes=ax)
countries.plot(axes=ax, alpha=0.25, linewidth=0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]
and the underlying dataset merges together the information we need

```py
data_merged.head(2)

    pop_est     continent   name_left   iso_a3  gdp_md_est  geometry    index_right     name_right
7   6909701     Oceania     Papua New Guinea    PNG     28020.0     MULTIPOLYGON (((141.00021 -2.60015, 142.73525 ...   59  Port Moresby
9   44293293    South America   Argentina   ARG     879400.0    MULTIPOLYGON (((-68.63401 -52.63637, -68.25000...   182     Buenos Aires
```

Here, I used `inner` join method but that's a parameter you can change if, for instance, you want to keep all points, including those not within a polygon.

Comment: So, in your example you're associating cities to countries. For associating countries to cities, should I use something like that ?

data_merged = geopandas.sjoin(cities, countries, how="inner", op='within')

ex. in cites dataset, I want to add a cell 'Argentina' in 'Buenos Aires' row

Comment: Yes I think it should be fine. `data_merged = geopandas.sjoin(cities, countries, how="inner", op='intersects')` might also produce the desired output in this situation.